# Netty. В какой момент очистится ChannelHandlerContext?

Tags: java, многопоточность, асинхронность, netty

В общем создал я сервер на основе `Netty` и назадавал хендлеров для `pipeline`.
Последний из них вот такой:

```
public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Package> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Package msg) throws Exception {
        //Тут какой-то код. О нем ниже.
    }
}
```

Мне нужно обработать пакет, сделать какие-то расчеты и отправить ответ. Причем расчеты выполняются в отдельном потоке. Чтобы обработать пакет, нужно примерно следующее (вставить на место комментария):

```
Something.add(msg); //(1)
ctx.writeAndFlush(msg.result);
```

Пройдет какое-то время, пакет дождется своей очереди на обработку и в него же запишется результат, который надо отправить назад (`ctx.writeAndFlush(msg.result);`).

Вот с этим у меня и проблемы. В случае (1) у меня есть большие сомнения, что пакет успеет обработаться к моменту отправки (все же разные потоки).

Какие есть варианты, которые позволят при такой логике точно обработать пакет до отправки, при этом будучи асинхронными?

Будет ли работать вариант с функцией обратного вызова? Что-то типа такого:

```
msg.callback = new Clb(){
    public void onFinish(){
        ctx.writeAndFlush(msg.result);
    }
}
Something.add(msg); //(2)
```

В общем и целом вопроса два: в какой момент `Netty` очистит/потеряет/сделает-что-то-еще-нехорошее `ChanellHandlerContext` и как мне до этого момента гарантированно успеть выполнить расчеты в другом потоке, чтобы успеть отправить ответ?

Answer (score 0):

В обработчик Вы можете передать в том числе и канал при помощи ctx.channel(). И затем использовать этот канал для записи в него результата. Я бы предложил Вам использовать некоторую структуру, которая будет содержать как сообщение, так и канал, по которому оно было передано и добавлять в обработку уже эту структуру. Таким образом, можно будет обработать сообщение, а затем по этому каналу передать результат.`